# Opening an URL?

Tags: android, url

I am trying to post data to the server in the following manner from Android.

```
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(URL_STRING);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
    startActivity(intent);
```

The URL_STRING when executed from the browser is posting the data. Through app it is not working. Where I am going wrong?

Comment: That is not posting data to server that is just opening a link using the browsers in the android device!

Comment: in the URL_STRING, I am constructing all the data required as well. In the same browser, if I manually enter the URL_STRING, it works. So I need a method to transfer the URL_STRING to the browser in such a way it opens the browser and later closes it. (The closing part is still not tried :-))

Comment: So it is the HTTP GET request???

Comment: HTTP PUT request; a form with 4 fields and if entered in sequence, takes the data and records

Comment: Found the solution. in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5489086/open-an-url-in-android-browser-avoid-multiple-tabs.  This way, solved both problems. This question can be closed.

Comment: Congratz I am glad you solved the problem **Happy Coding!**.